# Where can I read the full proof of the Banach-Mazur theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

The theorem is: every Banach separable space can be embedded in $C[0,1]$ linear and isometrically.

I actually found two books which contain the theorem and its proof:

-S. Banach, A Course of Functional Analysis [in Ukrainian], Kiev, 1948.

-L. A. Lyusternik and V. I. Sobolev, A Concise Course of Functional Analysis [in Russian], Nauka, Moscow, 1982.

But I can't read ukrainian nor russian.

Does anyone know a book in english with this proof? The functional analysis books I have read so far don't contain it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I found a reference:

*Topics in Banach Space Theory*, Fernando Albiac, page 18.

Comment: Thank you very much. It did the work.